# Passing multiple Table-Value parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters, insight.database

I am trying to insert multiple records into multiple tables using one call to a stored procedure which then calls into the corresponding stored procedures that insert into the individual tables.

I am using Insight.Database which has the option to generate table-value data types and stored procedures which take those table-values as parameters. Therefore, I thought I'd create my own procedure which takes multiple TVPs and call the generated Insight.Database procedures from within this SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_FOBO_InsertMany] 
(
    @CLIPF [dbo].[CLIPFTable] READONLY,
    @CLFPF [dbo].[CLFPFTable] READONLY,
    @POLBAPF [dbo].[POLBAPFTable] READONLY,
    @POL1PF [dbo].[POL1PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL2PF [dbo].[POL2PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL3PF [dbo].[POL3PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL4PF [dbo].[POL4PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL5PF [dbo].[POL5PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL6PF [dbo].[POL6PFTable] READONLY,
    @POL7PF [dbo].[POL7PFTable] READONLY,
    @POLBPF [dbo].[POLBPFTable] READONLY,
    @POLGPF [dbo].[POLGPFTable] READONLY,
    @POLQPF [dbo].[POLQPFTable] READONLY,
    @POLSIPF [dbo].[POLSIPFTable] READONLY
)
AS
    EXEC usp_CLIPF_InsertMany @CLIPF
    EXEC usp_CLFPF_InsertMany @CLFPF
    EXEC usp_POLBAPF_InsertMany @POLBAPF
    EXEC usp_POL1PF_InsertMany @POL1PF
    EXEC usp_POL2PF_InsertMany @POL2PF
    EXEC usp_POL3PF_InsertMany @POL3PF
    EXEC usp_POL4PF_InsertMany @POL4PF
    EXEC usp_POL5PF_InsertMany @POL5PF
    EXEC usp_POL6PF_InsertMany @POL6PF
    EXEC usp_POL7PF_InsertMany @POL7PF
    EXEC usp_POLBPF_InsertMany @POLBPF
    EXEC usp_POLGPF_InsertMany @POLGPF
    EXEC usp_POLQPF_InsertMany @POLQPF
    EXEC usp_POLSIPF_InsertMany @POLSIPF

GO
```

And the code which calls this procedure is as follows:

```
    public Task<Int32> Migrate(IEnumerable<ProposalRow> proposals, String source, Func<Guid, Package> packageProvider)
    {
        List<CLIPFRow> clipf = new List<CLIPFRow>();
        List<CLFPFRow> clfpf = new List<CLFPFRow>();
        List<POLBAPFRow> polbapf = new List<POLBAPFRow>();
        List<POL1PFRow> pol1pf = new List<POL1PFRow>();
        List<POL2PFRow> pol2pf = new List<POL2PFRow>();
        List<POL3PFRow> pol3pf = new List<POL3PFRow>();
        List<POL4PFRow> pol4pf = new List<POL4PFRow>();
        List<POL5PFRow> pol5pf = new List<POL5PFRow>();
        List<POL6PFRow> pol6pf = new List<POL6PFRow>();
        List<POL7PFRow> pol7pf = new List<POL7PFRow>();
        List<POLBPFRow> polbpf = new List<POLBPFRow>();
        List<POLGPFRow> polgpf = new List<POLGPFRow>();
        List<POLQPFRow> polqpf = new List<POLQPFRow>();
        List<POLSIPFRow> polsipf = new List<POLSIPFRow>();
        foreach (var proposal in proposals)
        {
            clipf.AddRange(this.MapCLIPF(proposal, source));
            pol1pf.Add(POL1PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            polbapf.AddRange(POLBAPFRow.From(proposal, source));
            pol2pf.AddRange(POL2PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            pol3pf.AddRange(POL3PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            pol4pf.AddRange(POL4PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            pol5pf.AddRange(POL5PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            pol6pf.AddRange(POL6PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            if (proposal.Smi.StrategyPlans != null && proposal.Smi.StrategyPlans.Any())
            {
                pol7pf.AddRange(POL7PFRow.From(proposal, source));
            }
            if (proposal.Smi.Beneficiary != null)
            {
                polbpf.Add(POLBPFRow.From(proposal, source));
            }
            polgpf.AddRange(POLGPFRow.From(proposal, source));
            if (proposal.Smi.Questionnaire != null && proposal.Smi.Questionnaire.Client != null)
            {
                polqpf.AddRange(POLQPFRow.From(proposal, source, packageProvider));
            }
            if (proposal.Smi.ProductMappingResult.BackOfficeProduct.BackOfficeProductCode.Equals("PUN4", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                polsipf.Add(POLSIPFRow.From(proposal, source));
            }
            clfpf.AddRange(CLFPFRow.From(proposal, source));
        }
        return base.DB.ExecuteAsync("usp_FOBO_InsertMany", new
        {
            CLIPF = clipf,
            CLFPF = clfpf,
            POLBAPF=polbapf,
            POL1PF =pol1pf,
            POL2PF =pol2pf,
            POL3PF =pol3pf,
            POL4PF =pol4pf,
            POL5PF =pol5pf,
            POL6PF =pol6pf,
            POL7PF =pol7pf,
            POLBPF =polbpf,
            POLGPF =polgpf,
            POLQPF =polqpf,
            POLSIPF=polsipf
        });
    }
```

Unfortunately, this is giving the following exception:

```
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Table-valued parameter 7 (""), row 1, column 8: Data type 0xE7 has an invalid data length or metadata length.
The data for table-valued parameter "@CLIPF" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 8037, state: 30
The statement has been terminated.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is right there in the error message. In table CLIPF, row 1 column 8. There is obviously some value in your data source that can't be cast to the underlying datatype in your table definition.

Comment: But the thing is that when I insert the SAME data by passing simple value parameters as opposed to passing a TVP, it actually works. So how could this be an issue with the data itself?

Comment: Because of the implicit casting going on here. It behaves a little differently when inserting to a table and setting a variable. My guess is you have data in the identified position that is too large for the column definition.